# PECL-Memcache can't read INTs set from PECL-Memcached

Tags: php, memcached, libmemcached

I'm in the process of switching applications from PHP [PECL-Memcache](http://pecl.php.net/package/memcache) client to [PECL-Memcached](http://pecl.php.net/package/memcached) and I'm hitting a snag.

It seems that if I set an INT value from PECL-Memcached that PECL-Memcache can't read it. I see something like:

```
MemcachePool::get(): Failed to unserialize data
```

If I cast the int values to a string, get operations work with memcache. Of course, this breaks increment/decrement.

Setting INTs from memcache and reading from memcached works fine.

I'm using:

- libmemcached 1.0.14
- pecl-memcache 3.0.6
- memcached 1.4.4
- php-pecl-memcached 2.1.0

I suspect it has something to do with the flags the different libraries are setting. Any suggestions on making these compatible with each other?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

there is incompatibility between pecl-memcache and php-pecl-memcacheD in types of values when flagged in memcached server.

pecl-memcache (memcache_pool.h) uses following flags:

```
#define MMC_TYPE_STRING 0x0000
#define MMC_TYPE_BOOL   0x0100
#define MMC_TYPE_LONG   0x0300
#define MMC_TYPE_DOUBLE 0x0700
```

when pecl-memcacheD uses this (php_memcached.c):

```
#define MEMC_VAL_IS_STRING     0
#define MEMC_VAL_IS_LONG       1
#define MEMC_VAL_IS_DOUBLE     2
#define MEMC_VAL_IS_BOOL       3
#define MEMC_VAL_IS_SERIALIZED 4
#define MEMC_VAL_IS_IGBINARY   5
#define MEMC_VAL_IS_JSON       6
```

so only type for STRING matches actually and can be decoded in same way by both